# Lenovo 14w Gen 2 Touchpad does not work on linux

Tags: linux, drivers, touchpad

Touchpad does not work.
it is not listed by `lspci` or `xinput`, but appears listed in `/sys/bus/acpi/devices`.

I tried everything that could be tried like compiling a newest version of the kernel and adding boot options in grub (spoiler alert) None of them did work. I'm out of ideas.